# Run Docker containers dynamically according to DB?

Tags: docker, nginx, dynamic, architecture, microservices

I'm developing an app which live-streams video and/or audio from different entities. Those entities' IDs and configurations are stored as records in my DB. My app's current architecture is something such as the following:

- a CRUD API endpoint for system-wide functionalities, such as logging in or editing an entity's configuration.
- N-amount of other endpoints (where N is the number of entities and every endpoint's route is defined by the specific entity's ID, like so: `"/:id/api/"`) for each entity's specific functionalities. Each entity is loaded by the app on initialization. Those endpoints are both a REST API handler and a WebSocket server for live-streaming media received from the backend which was configured for that entity.

On top of that, there's an NGINX instance which acts as a proxy and hosts our client files.

Obviously, this isn't very scalable at the moment (a single server instance handles an ever-growing amount of entities) and requires restarting my server's instance when adding/deleting an entity - which isn't ideal. I was thinking of splitting my app's server into micro-services: one for system-wide CRUD, and N others for each entity defined in my DB. Ultimately, I'd like those micro-services to be run as Docker containers. The problems (or questions to which I don't know the answers) I'm facing at the moment are:

1. How does one run Docker containers dynamically, according to a DB (or programmatically)? Is it even possible?
2. How does one update the running Docker container to be able to reconfigure that entity during run-time?
3. How would one even configure NGINX to proxy those dynamic micro-services? I'm guessing I'll have to use something like Consul?

I'm not very knowledgeable, so pardon me if I'm too naive to think I can achieve such architecture. Also, if you can think of a better architecture, I'd love to hear your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't run Docker containers dynamically without giving the server potentially unlimited root-level access over the whole host.  A server-per-connection or server-per-object layout is really unusual; it'd be more common to have a single server that could serve several concurrent streams on arbitrary objects, and I'd look at rearchitecting the system that way.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. That's basically my current architecture then, I'm just thinking of a situation where someday there might be lots and lots of entities to handle their logic and their streams, and I'm afraid my server will be overloaded. And there's also the issue of the possibility of an error which might make my whole server crash. Would you just use a Docker container for the whole app?

Comment: Having a dedicated service to stream data back is reasonable, separate from your main API.  You can scale by running multiple identical copies of the container and putting a load balancer in front of them.